# (Java)How to use try and catch inside of a actionlistener?

Tags: java, try-catch, actionlistener, ioexception

I have a question about the try/catch block inside of a listener. I tried to implement a JDialog that gives me the path for save a text of a JTextArea. In my code I save the file in try and have also the message from the catch part. What I need to change so that my catch only  captured(gives a message) if I have insert a wrong path?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame{
    public MyFrame() {
        super("SaveText");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

        final JTextField tFileName = new JTextField();
        final JTextArea tContent = new JTextArea();
        JButton bSave = new JButton("Save to File");
        JButton bReset = new JButton("Reset Content");

        JPanel pFile = new JPanel();
        pFile.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        pFile.add(new JLabel("Content:"));
        c.add(pFile, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel pForm = new JPanel();
        pForm.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        pForm.add(tContent);
        c.add(pForm, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel pButtons = new JPanel();
        pButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        pButtons.add(bSave);
        pButtons.add(bReset);
        c.add(pButtons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        bSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  try {
                      JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                      dialog.setTitle("Path");
                      JButton button= new JButton("Close");
                      dialog.add(tFileName);
                      dialog.add(button);
                      dialog.setSize(300, 100);
                      dialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
                      dialog.setVisible(true);
                      tContent.write(new FileWriter(tFileName.getText()));
                      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                             dialog.dispose();
                          }
                         });
                      } catch (IOException ex) {
                         System.out.println("Not possible to save the file                   ");
                  }
             }
         });
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrame test=new MyFrame();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by: What I need to change so that my catch only captured(gives a message) if I have insert a wrong path?

Comment: At this point, the code works when I give a right path or a wrong path. By a right path, it save the file, but the catch return the message ("Not possible to save the file ") also. By wrong path just return the message. Anything must be wrong, when the Try part works, why they return also the catch message? What I do wrong at this part of the code?

Comment: I don't understand what `By a right path, it save the file, but the catch return the message also` or `why they return also the catch message` means.

Comment: When I insert I right path for the file in the tFileName and this create a file in this path with the given name,it's don't make sense to execute the part inside of the catch. I thought this happen automatically. But doesn't. When the try part of the code works, then I want that the part of catch will be ignored. But this is not the case. The code creates a file and also give a message, that it is not possible to save(create) this file.

Comment: The only way in which the catch is called is if an IOException occurred. Include `ex.printStackTrace()` in the catch and see what threw the error.

Answer (score -1):

You are not doing right thing with your save. You are writing content to a non existing file. First you get the path, then check if the file on that path exists , then create a file and then finally write the content to the file.
I modified your `bSave.addActionListener`, to include a save button where you really need to save file.

Also couple of things , 
a) you need to use bufferedwriter to write to a file.
b) close bufferdwriter after writing.
c) dialog needs to be final.

```
 bSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  try
                  {
                      final JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                      dialog.setTitle("Path");
                      JButton sbutton= new JButton("Save");
                      final JTextField tFileName = new JTextField();
                      JButton cbutton = new JButton( "Close" );
                      dialog.add(tFileName);
                      dialog.add(sbutton);
                      dialog.add(cbutton);
                      dialog.setSize(300, 100);
                      dialog.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
                      dialog.setVisible(true);

                      sbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                      {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                            File file = new File(tFileName.getText());
                            if( !file.exists())
                            {
                              try {

                                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(file));
                                writer.write(tContent.getText());
                                writer.close();
                              } catch (IOException e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                  System.out.println("Not possible to save the file   because :  " + "\n" + e1.getMessage() );
                              }

                            }

                        }
                      });

                      cbutton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
                      {

                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                        {
                            dialog.dispose();

                        }

                      });
                  } 
                  catch (Exception ex) 
                  {
                      ex.printStackTrace();
                  }
             }
         });
```

With the above change, your new save dialog will look like :

[image]

Comment: `file.createNewFile();` is redundant here, or worse. `new FileWriter(file)` does the same thing, in the next line, which will now involve deleting the file you created with `createNewFile()`. Don't write pointless code.

Comment: @EJP It was for demo purpose. But I am removing that line, thank you.

Comment: In this case I need to use two catch blocks. Is it always the case when I try to write/save a file?

Comment: @Babi there is no need to use two catch blocks, you can safely remove the outer try..catch , I don't think any of the code in outside try catch throws exceptions. But yes, whenever you do file read/write you need to catch exceptions potentially thrown by the methods that involve file read/write.